# Setting Timer To Execute DB rows once every 1 second

Tags: c#, mysql, timer

Ok here is a better way of asking my question:

```
void PrepareTimers(List<int> _dataValues)
    {
        foreach (int dataValue in _dataValues)
        {
            ThreadingTimer timer = new ThreadingTimer(TimerAction, dataValue, 0, 1000);

        }
    }

    void TimerAction(object flag)
    {
        string myconstring = "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=alicosms;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=;";
        MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(myconstring);
        string u = "UPDATED";
        mycon.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE sms_data_bankasia set flag= @flag * 2 , sendingstatus = '" + u + "' WHERE flag = @flag", mycon);
        MySqlParameter param = new MySqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@flag";
        param.Value = flag;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

ThreadTimer gives me an error saying "namespace / type could not be found". Any fixes ?

Comment: and how did you program the timer to do its task ? does it have a problem ? are you getting any errors ?

Comment: This question shows little research.  The timer calls an event (I believe it's called Tick) every time it's interval is finished.  You can set this interval to 1000, which is one second.

Comment: For now there is no details inside Timer1_tick . I want a sketch of a script I could write that auto-updates the rows of mysql 'request' at table 'shoutbox' . There are 3 columns. ID (auto_increment), NickName and Post. The data stores fine, but now I'd need a button to retrieve the data. I clearly dont want this, I want the textbox to update by itself without having to create a button to update it. I thought I'd need a timer for this..

Comment: This doesn't help.  We need more details and won't write code for you.

Comment: How is this question related to C? I'm removing the tag for now; if that's a mistake please explain before re-adding it.

Comment: ThreadTimer gives me an error saying "namespace / type could not be found". Any fixes ?

here: http://pastebin.com/pf55eXhF

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 3):

There is no type named `ThreadingTimer` in the framework. Assuming you want [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx), you should add `using System.Threading;` to the top of your file (if you don't have it there already), then replace `ThreadingTimer` with just `Timer`.

Comment: still gives error .. says its an ambigious reference

Comment: Do you already have a class named Timer?

Comment: @DamageDz, what is the *full* error message? It should tell why is it an ambiguous reference.